# How do I convert to c# - passing a struct in C to a function?

Tags: c#, c

In C I have this function:

```
void(MyStruct* ms){
   ms->Prop1 = 2;
   ms->Prop2 = 3;

}
```

With Struct

```
struct{
    int Prop1;
    int Prop2;
}MyStruct;
```

What is the equivalent of this in C#?

What I'm not sure about its two things:

1. In C# do I use a Struct or Class?  Because I thought in C# structs are only value types.
2. Do I pass the struct or class with `ref` keyword?

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to write it in c#?

Comment: added the problems I was having

Comment: Don't you think it is easy to test with a few lines of code?

Comment: There are *tons* of tutorials, books, blogs, etc. describing how to help decide whether a type should be a struct or a class.  Take a look at some of them.  Think about what you think it should be and why.  Perhaps write it both ways and see what the consequences of the decision are for yourself.

Comment: I converted it already to C# but even if it works, how do I know if its the 'proper' way to convert it.  I guess I'm looking for the most exact translation because I'm converting a legacy C source code of many lines to C#

Answer (score 0):

As the code in C says *(a pointer to variable) you can use ref in C#. Also you can stick with struct unless you have any method implementations in that.

Comment: The type having methods doesn't exclude the use of a `struct` by any means.  Plenty of structs have methods.  Also, what's you're justification for suggesting the use of a `struct` here?

Answer (score 0):

`class` is probably what you're looking for as in your example code you're passing around pointers and modifying the instance.

For more information [see the MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx):

> A class is a reference type. When an object of the class is created, the variable to which the object is assigned holds only a reference to that memory. When the object reference is assigned to a new variable, the new variable refers to the original object. Changes made through one variable are reflected in the other variable because they both refer to the same data.
>
> A struct is a value type. When a struct is created, the variable to which the struct is assigned holds the struct's actual data. When the struct is assigned to a new variable, it is copied. The new variable and the original variable therefore contain two separate copies of the same data. Changes made to one copy do not affect the other copy.
>
> In general, classes are used to model more complex behavior, or data that is intended to be modified after a class object is created. Structs are best suited for small data structures that contain primarily data that is not intended to be modified after the struct is created.

As a `class` this could be represented simply as:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }

    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

And passed to a function as:

```
public void Test(MyClass s)
{
    s.Prop1 = 2;
    s.Prop2 = 3;
}
```

With no need for `ref`

Comment: So you feel that creating a mutable struct here is the idiomatic solution to this problem?

Comment: @Servy - I quoted the MSDN documentation to answer that. Explained further in edit though.

Comment: @Servy - just reread his question and realized I was answering a question he wasn't asking.